# dynamic pivot SQL Query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have table like below in DB2 where all these 3 columns are VARCHAR data type

```
DATE_F    FILE_NM   ROW_ID  COLUMN_NM   COLUMN_VAL 
20200131  ABC.TXT     1      ABC_COL1     123
20200131  ABC.TXT     1      ABC_COL2     XYZ
20201231  ABC.TXT     2      ABC_COL1     456
20201231  ABC.TXT     2      ABC_COL2     XY1
20200630  XYZ.TXT     1      XYZ_COL1     PQR
20200630  XYZ.TXT     1      XYZ_COL2     567
20200630  XYZ.TXT     1      XYZ_COL3     MNO
```

I need a dynamic PIVOT query which should select values for ABC_COL1 and ABC_COL2 in row format when FILE_NM filter is used as ABC.TXT

The same query should select the values for XYZ_COL1, XYZ_COL2 and XYZ_COL3 in row format when FILE_NM filter is used as XYZ.TXT

output should be like below when FILE_NM=ABC.TXT

```
DATE_F    ROW_ID   ABC_COL1   ABC_COL2    
20200131    1        123       XYZ
20201231    2        456       XY1
```

output should be like below when FILE_NM=XYZ.TXT

```
 DATE_F    ROW_ID     XYZ_COL1     XYZ_COL2     XYZ_COL3
20200630    1           PQR         567           MNO
```

So, one one query will be able to extract the data. Can any function or equivalent can do the task in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following generic Stored Procedure doing pivoting.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
create or replace procedure pivot
(
  in  sel_stmt varchar(4000)
, in  row_cols varchar(200)
, in  col_col  varchar(128)
, in  agg_col  varchar(128)
, in  agg_fn   varchar(10)
, in  tmp_tbl  varchar(128)
, in  null_ind varchar(10)
, out rc       int
, out msg      varchar(128)
, out stmt     varchar(4000)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT sets 1
BEGIN
 declare QUOT1        char(1) default '''';
 declare QUOT2        char(1) default '"';
 declare SQLCODE      int default 0;
 declare SQLTYPE_ID   int;
 declare SQLTYPE      varchar(128);
 declare SQLLENGTH    int;
 declare SQLSCALE     int;
 declare SQLNAME_DATA varchar(128);
 declare SQLTYPEF     varchar(128);
 declare col_val      varchar(4000);
 declare apo          varchar(1);
 declare l1 RESULT_set_LOCATOR VARYING;

 declare c2 cursor for s2;
 declare c_out cursor with return for s_out;

 declare EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
   GET DIAGNOSTICS EXCEPTION 1 MSG = MESSAGE_TEXT;
   set RC = SQLCODE;
 END;

 set col_col=upper(col_col);
 set agg_col=upper(agg_col);
 -- insert result of select statement into temp table
 set stmt = 'describe '||sel_stmt;
 call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(stmt);
 set stmt = '';
 associate result set locator (l1)
 with procedure SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD;
 allocate c1 cursor for result set l1;
 --open c1;
 fetch c1 into SQLTYPE_ID, SQLTYPE, SQLLENGTH, SQLSCALE, SQLNAME_DATA;
 while (SQLCODE!=100) do
   set SQLTYPEF = SQLTYPE
   ||case 
      when SQLTYPE IN ('DECIMAL', 'DECFLOAT', 'CHARACTER', 'VARCHAR') then 
         '('||RTRIM(CHAR(SQLLENGTH))
       ||case when SQLTYPE='DECIMAL' then ','||RTRIM(CHAR(SQLSCALE)) else '' end
       ||')'                                
      else ''
     end;
   if (col_col=SQLNAME_DATA) then
     set apo = 
      case 
       when SQLTYPE in ('DECIMAL', 'DECFLOAT', 'INTEGER', 'SMALLINT', 'BIGINT', 'REAL', 'DOUBLE') then '' 
       else QUOT1 
      end;
   end if;
   set stmt = stmt||', '||SQLNAME_DATA||' '||SQLTYPEF;
   fetch c1 into SQLTYPE_ID, SQLTYPE, SQLLENGTH, SQLSCALE, SQLNAME_DATA;
 end while;
 close c1;
 set stmt = 
   'declare global temporary table '||tmp_tbl||'('||substr(stmt, 3)
 ||') with replace on commit preserve rows not logged';
 execute immediate stmt;
 set stmt = 'insert into '||tmp_tbl||' '||sel_stmt;
 execute immediate stmt;

 -- construct select statement
 set stmt = 'select distinct rtrim(char('||col_col||')) from '||tmp_tbl||' order by 1';
 prepare s2 from stmt;
 set stmt='';
 open c2;
 fetch c2 into col_val;
 while (SQLCODE!=100) do
   set stmt = 
     stmt||', '||agg_fn||'('
   ||'case when '||col_col||' '
   ||case when col_val is null then 'IS NULL' else ('='||apo||replace(col_val, QUOT1, QUOT1||QUOT1)||apo) end
   ||' then '||agg_col||' end) as '||QUOT2||coalesce(replace(col_val, QUOT2, QUOT2||QUOT2), null_ind)||QUOT2;
   fetch c2 into col_val;
 end while;
 close c2;
 -- add to the select statement groups
 set row_cols = nullif(row_cols, '');
 set stmt = 
   'select '||case when row_cols is not null then row_cols||',' else coalesce(row_cols, '') end
 ||substr(stmt, 2)||' from '||tmp_tbl||' '
 ||case when row_cols is not null then ('group by '||row_cols||' order by '||row_cols) else '' end;
 -- execute this statement
 prepare s_out from stmt;
 open c_out;
END@
```

**Parameter description:**

| PARM | DESC |
| --- | --- |
| sel_stmt | Any valid SELECT statement for source data generation |
| row_cols | Comma separated list of column names used in the GROUP BY of final statement |
| col_col | A column name to pivot |
| agg_col | A column name to aggregate |
| agg_fn | Any valid Db2 aggregation function for the column name in "agg_col" parameter |
| tmp_tbl | DGTT name for intermediate result |
| null_ind | Null indicator |
| rc | Return code (OUT) |
| msg | Message text (OUT) |
| stmt | The final SELECT generated (OUT) |

**Brief description:**
DGTT passed in `tmp_tbl` is created and populated with the result of a SELECT statement passed in `sel_stmt`. All the column names specified in `row_cols`, `col_col`, `agg_col` must be in the SELECT list of this statement.
The final SELECT statement on this DGTT is dynamically generated using the following rules:

- for each distinct value `Vx` in the column name passed in `col_col` an additional column expression is generated like: `, <agg_fn> (case when <col_col> = Vx then <agg_col> end) as "Vx"` (`, <agg_fn> (case when <col_col> IS NULL then <agg_col> end) as "<null_ind>"` is used for `Vx` IS NULL), where `<parameter>` means string value passed with this parameter.
- `row_cols` column list is used in the `GROUP BY`, if it's not NULL.

**Use for your case:**

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.MYTAB 
(DATE_F, FILE_NM, ROW_ID, COLUMN_NM, COLUMN_VAL)
AS
(
VALUES
  ('20200131', 'ABC.TXT', 1, 'ABC_COL1', '123')
, ('20200131', 'ABC.TXT', 1, 'ABC_COL2', 'XYZ')
, ('20201231', 'ABC.TXT', 2, 'ABC_COL1', '456')
, ('20201231', 'ABC.TXT', 2, 'ABC_COL2', 'XY1')
, ('20200630', 'XYZ.TXT', 1, 'XYZ_COL1', 'PQR')
, ('20200630', 'XYZ.TXT', 1, 'XYZ_COL2', '567')
, ('20200630', 'XYZ.TXT', 1, 'XYZ_COL3', 'MNO')
) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
```

1-st call:

```
call pivot
(
  'select * from session.mytab where file_nm = ''ABC.TXT'''
, 'DATE_F, ROW_ID'
, 'COLUMN_NM'
, 'COLUMN_VAL'
, 'max'
, 'session.tab1'
, '-'
, ?, ?, ?
);
```

| DATE_F | ROW_ID | ABC_COL1 | ABC_COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200131 | 1 | 123 | XYZ |
| 20201231 | 2 | 456 | XY1 |

2-nd call:

```
call pivot
(
  'select * from session.mytab where file_nm = ''XYZ.TXT'''
, 'DATE_F, ROW_ID'
, 'COLUMN_NM'
, 'COLUMN_VAL'
, 'max'
, 'session.tab1'
, '-'
, ?, ?, ?
);
```

| DATE_F | ROW_ID | XYZ_COL1 | XYZ_COL2 | XYZ_COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20200630 | 1 | PQR | 567 | MNO |

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am getting an error while calling the procedure. SQL0104N An unexpected token "as" was found following "en COLUMN_VAL end)". Expected token may include : "AND". SQLSTATE = 42601

Comment: Are you able to run it as is including the `SESSION.MYTAB` table declaration? It would be good, if you provided exact parameter values, if you use some different call.

Comment: I am getting the same error when SESSION.MYTAB is used. SQL0104N An unexpected token "as" was found following "then COLUMN_VAL end)"

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: Platform Linux. DB2 version 11.1.0

Comment: Seems, that me and you use some different Db2 11.1. This must work on any Db2 for LUW. This works as is on my 11.1 as well. What tool do you use to run the routine? Does it support output parameters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233625/discussion-between-koushik-chandra-and-mark-barinstein).