# SQL query to combine child rows into a single row view

Tags: sql, view, db2

I have Activity parent table and Activities child table. I need an sql query to view the key as column name and value as column value as a single parent row. Tables and result shown in image. Key and values will change dynamically. Thanks

Activity table

```
Activityid     Activity  Time               
10            Activity1   Time1                 
11  Activity2   Time2                   
12  Activity3   Time3                   
13  Activity4   Time4
```

Activities table

```
Activityid  key value                   
10  Name    Mike                    
10  Account Saving                  
10  Type    Current                 
11  Party   ISG                 
11  loan    11233
```

If I give activityid 10, i should get result as below

```
Activityid  Activity    Time    Name    Account Type    
10         Activity1    Time1   Mike    Saving  Current
```

---

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please could you edit your question and include the data as text rather than an image?  The web-editor has options for formatting that data.  This allows us to copy and paste the data in to answers or test with that data, rather than each person having to transcribe that data.  More information on why is found here : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: `Key and values will change dynamically.` This is a SQL Anti Pattern.  SQL Is designed and implemented such that datasets have fixed columns with fixed data types.  While what you've asked for can be accomplished with what is referred to as "dynamic SQL" *(code that reads the data and the writes new code to accommodate  the dynamic columns)* is is generally not the right approach.  Which brings up the question; why do you want to do this?  If it's for presenting the data to a human, do that transformation outside of SQL.  If it's for further SQL processing, keep the current (normalised) format

Answer (score 1):

This sort of algorithms is called "pivoting".
You may use a generic routine described at the link [dynamic pivot SQL Query in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908450/dynamic-pivot-sql-query-in-db2) in Db2.
Use the following call to get the desired result set for your case:

```
CALL PIVOT
(
'
SELECT A.*, B.key, B.value
FROM Activity A
JOIN Activities B ON B.Activityid = A.Activityid
WHERE A.Activityid = 10
'  
, 'Activityid, Activity, Time'
, 'key'
, 'value'
, 'max'
, 'SESSION.PIVOT'
, '-'
, ?, ?, ?
);
```