# How to use pivot in SQL/DB2?

Tags: sql, db2, pivot

How can I use pivot in DB2 (or SQL) if I have 2 tables?

Table1

| Userid | Username |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Mike |
| 002 | Tomm |
| 003 | Suse |

Table2

| Userid | Date_visit | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-10-01 | bread |
| 001 | 2021-10-01 | chocolate |
| 001 | 2021-10-03 | pasta |
| 002 | 2021-10-06 | pizza |
| 002 | 2021-10-08 | camera |
| 002 | 2021-10-08 | usb-stick |
| 002 | 2021-10-22 | gloves |
| 002 | 2021-11-04 | split logs |

I need the output like this

Output

| Userid | Username | month | item1 | item2 | item3 | item 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Mike | October 21 | bread | chocolate | pasta |  |
| 002 | Tomm | October 21 | pizza | camera | usb-stick | gloves |
| 002 | Tomm | November 21 | split logs |  |  |  |

Thank you!

Comment: In SQL queries you need to know in advance the number of resulting columns. Is that a given in your case (item 1-4)? If it's not then you'll need to run an initial query to determine this, and then you can assemble a dynamic SQL according to the initial query.

Comment: Thanks for answering The Impaler. No, the number of resulting columns is not known. Do you have an idea how I combine the so named initial query with dynamic  SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivoting in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)

Comment: Hi Charles thanks for answering. The suggested topic did not answer my question, there the item names are known, in my table it can be everything. I need to list all items of a purchase only in one row grouped for each month. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a generic stored procedure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908450/dynamic-pivot-sql-query-in-db2/67918115#67918115).
The corresponding call:

```
call pivot
(
  'SELECT B.USERID, A.USERNAME, TO_CHAR (B.DATE_VISIT, ''Month YY'') AS MONTH, B.ITEM, ''ITEM'' || ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY B.USERID, A.USERNAME, TO_CHAR (B.DATE_VISIT, ''Month YY'') ORDER BY B.ITEM) AS ITEM_NM FROM TABLE1 A JOIN TABLE2 B ON B.USERID = A.USERID'
, 'USERID, USERNAME, MONTH'
, 'ITEM_NM'
, 'ITEM'
, 'max'
, 'session.tab1'
, '-'
, ?, ?, ?
);
```