# IBM DB2 PIVOT A TABLE FULL OF DATES

Tags: database, date, db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I have this table in DB2:

```
   DATE
----------
09/11/2021
06/10/2021
28/11/2021
17/11/2021
11/10/2021
24/11/2021
07/11/2021
30/11/2021
```

I want to count how many times a date appeared in the table and group it by year and month, and display it like this:

```
| YEAR | OCTOBER | NOVEMBER |
----------------------------
| 2021 |    2    |    6     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As months are a known quantity you could use a sum of a case statement:

```
select year(datecol) as year
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as jan
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as feb
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as mar
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as apr
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as may
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as jun
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as jul
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) as aug
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as sep
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as oct
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as nov
  ,sum(case when month(datecol) = 12 then 1 else 0 end) as dec
 from datetest 
 group by year(datecol)
 order by 1;
```

That will give you output similar to this:

```
YEAR        JAN         FEB         MAR         APR         MAY         JUN         JUL         AUG         SEP         OCT         NOV         DEC
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
       2018           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           3           0
       2019           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1           2           0
       2020           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           1           1           0
       2021           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           0           2           6           0
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may use a generic routine described at the link [dynamic pivot SQL Query in Db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908450/dynamic-pivot-sql-query-in-db2).
Use the following call to get the desired result set for your case:

```
CALL PIVOT
(
  'SELECT YEAR (DATE) AS YEAR, TO_CHAR (DATE, ''MONTH'') AS MONTH FROM DATES'  
, 'YEAR'
, 'MONTH'
, 'MONTH'
, 'count'
, 'SESSION.PIVOT'
, '-'
, ?, ?, ?
);
```

The result is:

| YEAR | NOVEMBER | OCTOBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 6 | 2 |