# How to transpose ROW to Column in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

in DB2, how can we transpose a simple “select * from ***TABLE*** fetch first 1 rows only” query output row into column?

***TABLE*** name could be dynamic so (*) in select is a must..

TIA for ur inputs and suggestion.

Example:

from:

| F1 | F2 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI |

to:

| F1 |
| --- |
| ABC |
| DEF |
| GHI |

Comment: use `top 1 `  in your query.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I am able to fetch 1 row... But I also want it to be transposed to column.

Comment: I've edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic pivot SQL Query in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908450/dynamic-pivot-sql-query-in-db2)

Comment: Checked, apparently it did not.

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: platform is IBMi (as400) V7R4M000

Comment: How can you guarantee that all columns in every table are union compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't.
There's nothing in Db2 for IBM i that will do this with `SELECT *` and a dynamic table.

Long answer, you can build a stored procedure or user defined table function that **dynamically builds and executes** an old school statement that looks like so:

```
with firstRow as 
  (select F1, F2, F3 from table fetch first row only)
select F1
from firstRow
UNION ALL 
select F2
from firstRow
UNION ALL
select F3
from firstRow;
```

Alternately, since you're on v7.4, you could **build and execute a dynamic statement** that `CONCAT` the fields into string list and then use the [SPLIT() table function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-split-table-function)  to deconstruct the the list into rows.

Lastly, you might be able to **build and execute a dynamic statement** that uses the JSON functions to build a JSON array which could then be deconstructed into rows with the [JSON_TABLE()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-json-table) function.

But as emphasized, in all cases you'll need to know column and table names for the actual SELECT.  Thus the need to dynamically build the statement.

Comment: yup seems you are right. I went thru CL coding to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Try a generic table function like below.
The 1-st parameter is whatever valid SELECT statement text.
The 2-nd parameter is a list of column names of this SELECT statement to convert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYSCHEMA.UNPIVOT (P_STMT VARCHAR (32000), P_COLLIST VARCHAR (100))
RETURNS TABLE (C VARCHAR (100))
BEGIN
    DECLARE SQLCODE INT;
    DECLARE V_VAL VARCHAR (100);
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR S1;

    PREPARE S1 FROM 'SELECT V.C_ FROM (' || P_STMT || '), TABLE (VALUES ' || P_COLLIST || ') V (C_)';
    OPEN C1;
    L1: LOOP
        FETCH C1 INTO V_VAL;
        IF SQLCODE = 100 THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
        PIPE (V_VAL);
    END LOOP L1;
    CLOSE C1;
    RETURN;
END
@
```

You must either:

construct the SELECT statement to return only string columns and specify a simple column list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE (MYSCHEMA.UNPIVOT (
    'SELECT * FROM (VALUES (CHAR (1), ''2'', CHAR (CURRENT DATE))) T (C1, C2, C3)'
  , 'C2, C3'
)) T
```

or explicitly cast every non-string column in the list of columns to CHAR:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE (MYSCHEMA.UNPIVOT (
    'SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, ''2'', CURRENT DATE)) T (C1, C2, C3)'
  , 'CHAR (C1), CHAR (C3)'
)) T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with LATERAL

```
select 
   Key, value
from mytable T,
      lateral (values ('F1', t.F1)
                      , ('F2', t.F2) 
                      , ('F3', t.F3)
                      ) as mypivot(key, value);
```