# Pivot table with dynamically maximum case

Tags: sql, database, db2

please helpe with this query. I have this tables:

high_price :

```
id_user   diagnosis_date    mot
1         18/11/2021        Censo
2         9/05/2022         Seguimiento
```

medicines_user:

```
id_user cod_medicine
1       25
1       32
1       6
2       8
2       25
```

medicine:

```
cod    name
25     acetaminofen
6      dolex
32     diclofenaco
8      tiamina
60     ibuprofeno
```

I need this result:

```
id_user diagnosis_date  mot         med_1         med_2        med_3
1       18/11/2021      Censo       acetaminofen  diclofenaco  dolex
2       9/05/2022       Seguimiento tiamina       acetaminofen
```

I want to try something like this:

```
SELECT
    hp.id_user,
    hp.diagnosis_date,
    hp.mot,
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.cod = '25' THEN mu.name ELSE '-' END) AS "med_1",
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.cod = '32' THEN mu.name ELSE '-' END) AS "med_2",
    MAX(CASE WHEN m.cod = '6' THEN mu.name ELSE '-' END) AS "med_3",
    ...
FROM
    salud.high_price hp
JOIN salud.medicines_user mu ON
    hp.id_user = mu.id_user
JOIN salud.medicine m ON
    mu.cod_medicine = m.cod
```

but this would not help me, since I need the list of medications to be dynamic, because the medication table corresponds to about 8000 records. How could I get the maximum total that any user could have? Assuming a user reached a maximum of 8 medications, then the table should be something like, med_1, med_2, med_3, ..., med_8.
I hope I have made myself understood. Thank you. I am using DB2 from IBM.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a row number to the medication then pivot using the rownumber

Here the medications are ordered by name

```
select 
  id_user, diagnosis_date, mot,
  max(case rn when 1 then name end) as "med_1",
  max(case rn when 2 then name end) as "med_2",
  max(case rn when 3 then name end) as "med_3",
  max(case rn when 4 then name end) as "med_4",
  max(case rn when 5 then name end) as "med_5",
  max(case rn when 6 then name end) as "med_6",
  max(case rn when 7 then name end) as "med_7",
  max(case rn when 8 then name end) as "med_8"
from (
  select
    id_user, char(diagnosis_date, eur) diagnosis_date, mot, rownumber() over(partition by id_user, diagnosis_date, mot order by name) rn, name
  from high_price
    inner join medicine_users using(id_user)
    inner join medicine on cod = cod_medicine
)
group by id_user, diagnosis_date, mot
```

| ID_USER | DIAGNOSIS_DATE | MOT | med_1 | med_2 | med_3 | med_4 | med_5 | med_6 | med_7 | med_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18.11.2021 | Censo | acetaminofen | diclofenaco | dolex | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 22.05.2022 | Seguimiento | acetaminofen | tiamina | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_bJmfEIJ)

Comment: cool solution, but it's not dynamic

Comment: @nfgl Exactly, but it's not dynamic. Thanks. I need it ot be dynamic.

Comment: @AlJw does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908450/dynamic-pivot-sql-query-in-db2/67918115#67918115) answer the question ?